# EF Core 2.1 how to update data in related table

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I am new to EF core and have created a test project following this tutorial [getting started with EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db)

It's a blog with some posts.

I've updated the Edit GET method to include the posts

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var blog = await _context.Blog.Include(x => x.Post).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.BlogId == id);
        if (blog == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(blog);
    }
```

I have updated the model in order to be able to index the posts.

```
    public partial class Blog
{
    public Blog()
    {
        Post = new List<Post>();
    }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Post> Post { get; set; }
}
```

And in my Edit.cshtml I have added this section to display the posts:

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Post.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Post[i].Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Post[i].Content" class="form-control" />                    
            </div>
        }
```

However when I try to update an updated Post object, it just gets added to the collection rather than updating the existing. This means my posts gets doubled each time I update them.

Here's my Edit POST method. I've checked that the value of blog contains the correct values in the posts collection.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("BlogId,Url,Post")] Blog blog)
    {
        if (id != blog.BlogId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(blog);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!BlogExists(blog.BlogId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(blog);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's no hidden input field for the `PostId`, so the Posts that are part of the Blog in your POST action are treated as new records and inserted.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Post[i].PostId" />
        <label asp-for="Post[i].Title" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Post[i].Content" class="form-control" />                    
</div>
```

Comment: Great, it works. That was not quite obvious, not for me at least. Thanks.